# How to copy a row conditionally?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I've searched for a similar question here, but haven't been able to find something that answers my issue.

I'm a mediocre user of Excel 2010 with no experience in macro's. I have a dataset where each row represents a data entry. Let's say each row can be for each of its values (the columns) the maximum or minimum of the entire dataset. How can I create a row at the top where the, for instance, maximum row is shown dynamicly? So when extra data is added to the bottom of the dataset, the new maximum (if applicable) is shown in that row at the top.

[image]

So, in this example above, if for instance Brad is added, and Brad has bought for 40 euros of bread and 20 euros of wine, his row is shown/copied/duplicated to row 2, like so:

[image]

Comment: I'm not an expert here, but do you have much knowledge of pivot tables? Currently there is a good video (1 of 3) on [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CuhQ9lSMmjg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED ANSWER:

Please try this:
Where A1 is:

```
=INDEX(A4:A10;MATCH(B1;B4:B10;0))
```

and B1 is:

```
=MAX(B5:B7)
```

[image]

OLD ANSWER:

I am not sure if I understand you correctly but it sounds like

```
=max(A1:A20)
```

or

```
 =min(A1:A20)
```

is what you need to get the max/min values for your row, where your row starts at A1 and ends at A20. If you add new values to eg. A21 you would need to alter that forula or you could also change the formula to

```
=max(A1:A1000)
```

for eg. It is not necessary that you have values in all these cells.

**EDIT**: Oh i see your problem now but I need to leave. I will reply you later if theres no one faster ;) 
Maybe have a look at vlookup meanwhile

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't need just the max. or min. I need an entire row to be copied because of one max. or min. value in that row (the question is extended with an example now).

Comment: Edited my answer. tell me if you have problems.

Comment: It does the job perfectly, and gives me also the opportunity to do that match in the other columns as well! Thank you!